# PHPCS disallow dynamic property

Tags: php, phpcs

I have created a project based on php 7.4. I plan to move to php 8.2.

In php 8.2, in a class, it is forbidden to declare properties dynamically.
I would like to add a rule to PHPCS that would highlight the places where this happens so I can gradually correct my code.

What is the PHPCS rule that describes this? Should I use a different solution to PHPCS or install a plugin?

I tried looking in the online docs for PHPCS rules, but without success.